# Can not received any touch events from QLPreviewController.view

Tags: ios, swift

In order to customisze a preview file controller, I create a `DocumentPreviewController: UIController`, and then `DocumentPreviewController.view.addSubView(QLPreviewController.view)`. If I present `QLPreviewController.view` with full screen, I can't receive any `touch event` even I had add `UIGestureRecognizer` for `QLPreviewController.view` and monitor all touch events in `DocumentPreviewController`. Could anyone can help me?

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook

class CustomiseDocumentPreviewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
 {

    var url : String!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   let previewController =  CustomisePreviewController()
    previewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)
    previewController.filePath = url

    let singleGuesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    singleGuesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GlipDocumentPreviewController._singleTap))
    singleGuesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleGuesture.delegate = self
    previewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    previewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleGuesture)
    previewController.view.multipleTouchEnabled = true

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(previewController.view)
}

func _singleTap()
{
    if self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden
    {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
    //        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = !(self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden)
    print("====")
}


public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

public func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

===========

```
  import QuickLook
  class CustomisePreviewController: QLPreviewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate
 {

var filePath : String?
      override func viewDidLoad()
      {
    self.dataSource = self
    self.listSubViewOfView(self.view)`
 }

func numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController(controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
}

func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, shouldOpenURL url: NSURL, forPreviewItem item: QLPreviewItem) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func previewControllerDidDismiss(controller: QLPreviewController)
{

}

func previewControllerWillDismiss(controller: QLPreviewController)
{

}
```

I have add single touch event to Both `CustomiseDocumentPreviewController.view` and `CustomisePreviewController.view`, as you can see from my code, `CustomisePreivewController.view` in the top half of the screen, If I touch on that space, nothing happens. However, If I touch on the below screen, it works.
I had searched for several days and it seems that we can not get the touch events from `QLPreviewController` ?.
1. If you have any method that can listen to the 'QLPreviewController.view' touch events, please help me.
2. If it can not, how will you do if you need customise a preview file controller.

Comment: We need more code to help you out. Edit your question and paste the relevant code. You can also add s screenshot of your view or storyboard, if you think it might be useful to us.

Comment: What is "QLPreviewController"? It looks to me like it's similar to UITableView or UICollectionView or something related. This could be the reason why you're not receiving touch events. Maybe try google search: "swift uicollectionview gesture recogniser".